# Why does scanf accept more characters than there is room for in the buffer?

Tags: c, buffer, scanf

See the following code:

```
int main()
{
  char test[3];

  scanf("%s", test);
  __fpurge(stdin);
  printf("%s", test);
}
```

The program should record only 3 characters, but when I type, for example, 8 characters, the program records all 8! This should not happen. The correct would record 3 characters, because the `scanf` do it?

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour*. That means anything can happen, including apparently working properly. I did not tie my shoe laces. Why did I not fall over? It's a non question.

Comment: You didn't tell `scanf()` how much space was available for the data, so it assumes there must be enough space available for anything that's entered.  So it does its best to store the 8 characters — but that overflows the array you specified, leading to undefined behaviour.  If you learned on a modern language with automatic protection from buffer overflows, learning C is going to be rough.  The C environment does not protect you from your misunderstanding or careless behaviour.  (And `char test[3]` can only hold a two-character string, plus the null terminator.)

Comment: Curious, why did you _expect_ C to not accept more characters than there is room for in the buffer?

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` accepts more data than you can fit in `test` because you allow it to do so by using `%s` without a limit. This is dangerous, and must be avoided in production code.

Replace `%s` with `%3s` to fix this problem. If you want to read three characters, `test` must be four-characters wide to accommodate null terminator:

```
char test[4];
scanf("%3s", test);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pass `test` to `scanf()`, you are passing nothing but a pointer to the first character of your buffer, so `scanf()` has no idea how large your buffer is. It will happily accept as many characters as you type, and it will store them all in there.  So, when you type more than 2 characters, you are causing `scanf()` to write characters (plus the zero asciiz terminator character) past the end of your buffer.  Normally, what is to be expected in such a case is a program crash.

The fact that you did not experience a crash is largely coincidence, what is probably happening is that the compiler has allocated room for more than 3 characters in the stack due to alignment considerations, possibly room for 8 characters or more.  If you type enough characters, your program will surely crash.

For this reason, this usage of `scanf()` is considered completely unsafe. One should never use `scanf()` like that when doing any serious coding.  Instead you should specify the width of your string, like this: `"%2s"`.  (Note that you must specify a number which is smaller than the size of your buffer by one, in order to account for the zero asciiz terminator character that will be automatically appended by `scanf()`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I just did, I was looking at the documentation.  I remembered a format string syntax where you could pass the buffer and the size of the buffer as parameters, instead of having to embed the size of the buffer in the string literal, but I could not find it.  It was probably some Microsoft C extension.

Comment: @MikeNakis that would be `scanf_s` which needs additional arguments for the size of some types of format specifier. It is supposed to be "safer" but in reality it is just as tricky as the original `scanf`, and if you get it wrong, is actually ***more*** dangerous, since you might by mistake be passing a size argument such as `2` for an *address* argument.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), where you can indeed write `%*.*s` to specify the minimum field width and the 'precision' (maximum number of characters to display) and it will take the values corresponding to the `*` from the parameter list.  One of the issues with `scanf()` is that it has no equivalent functionality (in a `scanf()` format string, a `%*s` means read, but do not assign, a string).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I remember being disappointed to discover that `scanf` uses the `*` in a different way from `printf`. In the latter, the `*` width is a function argument. Unfortunately AFAIK  `scanf` needs that to be hard coded, apart from MSVC extension `scanf_s` which *requires* a width argument for `%s`